# Getting Subject Position of a student from total scores using PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, dense-rank

I am working on a project that gets subject average, subject position and class position of a student in a class.

My challenge now is how to get Subject Position and class position of a student in a class.

This is my Table arrangement:

table name=academic_result

```
REG | class | session | term | subject | total
01  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | csc101  | 85
02  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | csc101  | 90
01  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | bus101  | 70
02  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | bus101  | 90
01  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | chem101 | 75
02  | js1   |200/2001 | 1T   | chem101 | 85
```

```
<?php
                      
// Subject Ranking
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT REG, term, subject, session, total, dense_rank() OVER( partition by subject ORDER BY total desc ) 
AS 'dense_rank' FROM academic_result WHERE class=? AND term=? AND session=?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $class, $term, $session);
$stmt->execute();
$checkSubject = $stmt->get_result();

$result_SUBPO = $checkSubject->fetch_assoc();
echo ordinal($result_SUBPO['dense_rank']);
?>
```

```
Subject | Total | Subject ranking | class position 
csc101  | 85    |1st              |
bus101  | 70    |1st              | 
chem101 | 75    |1st              |
```

this what the query out put looks like, this is the result of a student with Reg No(01). Subject ranking(subject position) for a student is always 1st, this is where am having problem. The subject ranking (subject position) is alto vary depending on their subject total score.

I still want to get Class position of a student from the table.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially where it mentions not posting pictures of code or data - especially not blurry ones with the text truncated. Post it as text. You can [edit] your post. Try to help those who want to help you. See also how to make a [mre] of your issue. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - for future reference

Comment: It's good to remove the pictures but you have also removed any description of the problem, and any indication of the expected query result, based on the sample data. That still needs to be there (in text form) otherwise it's very hard to see exactly what you want. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's better now. I have nominated the question to be re-opened. Be patient.